# Not able to fetch value of variable outside function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying get value of variable "corpus" outside reactive function. I'm creating Shiny app where it is mandatory to define readcsv <- read.csv(inFile$datapath) inside reactive function. Can anybody please help how I can get the dataframe value of corpus outside reactive function data1().

**server.R**

```
data1 <- reactive({
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile)){
return(NULL)
}
#Read csv file
readcsv <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)

#Create Corpus
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(readcsv$Tweets))
```

})

**ui.R**

```
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
accept = c(
"text/csv",
"text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
".csv")
)
```

Comment: you want to have the value of `data1` to be that of `corpus`?

Comment: so you are saying that by doing corpus <- data(), corpus will have its value as Corpus(VectorSource(readcsv$Tweets)) i.e. corpus will have corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(readcsv$Tweets)) ??? Is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

The following will put the output of `Corpus(...)` in `data1`

```
data1 <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){
        return(NULL)
    }
    #Read csv file
    readcsv <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)

    #Create Corpus
    Corpus(VectorSource(readcsv$Tweets))
})
```

Then you can use it anywhere in `server` like so

```
corpus <- data1()
```